# Referential integrity over table portion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm designing a database and can't figure out how to model referential integrity.

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE Groups
(
GroupId INT PRIMARY KEY,
GroupName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE GroupMembers
(
GroupId INT NOT NULL,
MemberId INT NOT NULL,
MemberName VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT pk_GroupMember PRIMARY KEY (GroupId, MemberId)
)

CREATE TABLE Missions
(
MissionId INT PRIMARY KEY,
GroupId INT NOT NULL,
MissionName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE MissionRollAssignments
(
MissionId INT NOT NULL,
MemberId INT NOT NULL,
MemberRoll VARCHAR(50)  --This will probably become RollId and move details to another table
)
```

Every mission will have assignments for some/all members of the corresponding group. There will be several missions associated with each group, but only one mission per group is active at a given time.

My question is:

Is it possible to enforce referenciay integrity for roll assignments such that only members 
of the corresponding group (given by the MissionId) are selected? I know I can filter this from the GUI, but I'd feel more comfortable if I could create a FK constraint from MissionRollAssignments to GroupMembers while considering the GroupId indicated in the Mission.

A second question would be if you guys think this is a good way to model my domain, or maybe I should try a different approach.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Best regards,
Awer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put GroupId into MissionRollAssignments and then add two constraints as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE MissionRollAssignments
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (GroupId, Memberid)
 REFERENCES GroupMembers (GroupId, Memberid);

ALTER TABLE MissionRollAssignments
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (GroupId, MissionId)
 REFERENCES Missions (GroupId, MissionId);
```

To achieve this SQL Server first requires a (redundant) UNIQUE constraint on (GroupId, MissionId) in the Missions table. Other DBMSs are not so strict but SQL Server requires a FOREIGN KEY constraint to match exactly the columns of a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: I've been experimenting with this and it actually works fine! Thanks for your help. Could you please give me a little explanation about how this is accomplishing what I wanted?

Comment: Hi sqlvogel. I think I get it now, but now I'm thinking that with the introduction of GroupId in MissionRoleAssignments now the DB is not in 3NF any more. Am I correct? Is this a problem?

Comment: You are right because of MissionId->GroupId non-key dependency in MissionRollAssignments. However, that constraint is still effectively enforced by the FK constraint so there is no loss of integrity there. The alternative of not having GroupId in that table would make it harder to enforce the business rule you said you wanted. This kind of situation commonly arises in SQL. SQL's support for integrity constraints is quite limited and the only way to enforce certain business rules is to denormalize. You have to decide how much it's worth to you to enforce the rule in the database.

Comment: Great! This has been very helpful. Thank you very much for taking the time to write this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Foreign Keys to reinforce this, eg Mission.GroupId should refer to Group.GroupId.

Comment: To enforce Assignments over Group Members, you should probably change MissionRollAssignments table to include GroupMemberId (new column) instead of MemberId.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to enforce referenciay integrity for roll assignments such that only members of the corresponding group (given by the MissionId) are selected?

Yes. You need to use identifying relationships to propagate the `GroupId` all the way down to the bottom of this "diamond-shaped" dependency, similar to this:

[image]

Note `FK1` and `FK2` in front of `MissionRollAssignment.GroupId`, indicating that foreign keys exist up the both "sides" of this "diamond-shaped" dependency.

---

As single active mission can be modeled as a foreign key in the opposite direction, in this case as `Group {GroupId, ActiveMissionNo}` that references the `Mission` primary key.

Such circular foreign key presents a "chicken-and-egg" problem on a DBMS that doesn't support deferred constraints (which SQL Server doesn't). However, you can just leave `Group.ActiveMissionNo` NULL-able, so a DBMS that enforces foreign keys in a [MATCH SIMPLE](http://wiki.burnsoft.net/KB58.ashx)  fashion (which SQL Server does) will ignore the whole composite foreign key if just one of its fields is NULL. This will allow you to temporarily "disable" the foreign key and break the "chicken-and-egg" cycle when inserting new data.